# IndexError: list index out of range con python

Tags: python

El problema es: Dada una matriz a, su tarea es aplicarle la siguiente mutación:

```
Array A muta a una nueva matriz B de la misma longitud.
```

Para cada uno `i` de 0 hasta a.length - 1 inclusive,

```
b[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]
```

Si algún elemento de la suma

```
a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]
```

no existe, se considera que es 0.

Por ejemplo, b[0] igual 0 + a[0] + a[1].

**Ejemplo**

Para a = [4, 0, 1, -2, 3], la salida debería ser

```
solution(a) = [4, 5, -1, 2, 1].
```

Explicación:

```
b[0] = 0 + a[0] + a[1] = 0 + 4 + 0 = 4
b[1] = a[0] + a[1] + a[2] = 4 + 0 + 1 = 5
b[2] = a[1] + a[2] + a[3] = 0 + 1 + (-2) = -1
b[3] = a[2] + a[3] + a[4] = 1 + (-2) + 3 = 2
b[4] = a[3] + a[4] + 0 = (-2) + 3 + 0 = 1
```

Entonces, la matriz de respuesta mutada es [4, 5, -1, 2, 1].

Intente así:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

def solution(a):

    salida = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        alfa = i-1
        beta = i+1
            
        if beta != None and alfa<0:           
            salida.append(0 + a[i] + a[beta])
            print(i)
            print(salida)
        elif beta !=None:
            salida.append(a[alfa] + a[i] + a[beta])
            print(i)
            print(salida)
       
        elif i is a[-1]:
            salida.append(a[alfa] + a[i] + 0)
            print(i)
            print(salida)
        
            
    print(salida)
    
    
            
solution(a)
```

pero me da este resultado:

```
0
[3]
1
[3, 6]
2
[3, 6, 9]
3
[3, 6, 9, 12]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/Documentos/python/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    solution(a)
  File "/home/gabriel/Documentos/python/test.py", line 16, in solution
    salida.append(a[alfa] + a[i] + a[beta])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

necesito iluminacion!!!

Comment: Buen día, lo siento, no entendí nada de lo que pusiste en el primer párrafo, no sé si los números entre las letras vengan en el enunciado original pero creo que es complicado entender lo que deseas hacer, ¿Podrías aclarar el enunciado?

Comment: `elif beta !=None:` esta condición siempre se cumple, por lo `elif i is a[-1]:` nunca llega a ejecutarse.

Comment: `i is a[-1]` ¿Quisistes decir `i == a[-1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primer consejo: cuando enfrentes problemas donde los indices se te pueden salir de rango, usa una función para recuperar la información.

En este caso, hago una función que recibe una lista y un indice,:

```
def get(lista, i):
    return lista[i] if (0 <= i < len(lista)) else 0
```

Si el indice es válido, devuelve el elemento correspondiente de la lista. Si no, devuelve cero.

Con esto ya puedo evaluar la formula directamente, sin preocuparme de cuales son los indices en particular:

```
b = []
for i in range(len(lista)):
    b.append(get(lista, i - 1) + get(lista, i) + get(lista, i + 1))
```

#### Demo

```
lista = [4, 0, 1, -2, 3]

def get(lista, i):
    return lista[i] if (0 <= i < len(lista)) else 0

b = []
for i in range(len(lista)):
    b.append(get(lista, i - 1) + get(lista, i) + get(lista, i + 1))

print(b)
```

produce:

```
[4, 5, -1, 2, 1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias Candid muy elegante tu solucion!!!!

Answer (score 1):

@CandidMoe ya respondió con una solución más óptima, pero te he arreglado el código para que veas en que estabas fallando.

1. elif beta !=None es equivalente elif True por lo quitando los beta!=None y metiéndole un else en el que se queda sin condición funciona.
2. El último problema que tenías es que usabas el is que sirve para comparar si proceden del mismo objeto las dos variables, por lo que es mejor == y que a[-1]
   coge el último valor, no el último índice, para eso puedes hacer len(a)-1

   ```
   a = [4, 0, 1, -2, 3]

   def solution(a):

    salida = []
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        alfa = i-1
        beta = i+1

        if   alfa<0:           
            salida.append(0 + a[i] + a[beta])
            print(i)
            print(salida)
        elif i == len(a)-1:
            salida.append(a[alfa] + a[i] + 0)
            print(i)
            print(salida)
        else:
            salida.append(a[alfa] + a[i] + a[beta])
            print(i)
            print(salida)




    print(salida)



   solution(a)
   ```

Comment: Gracias rexxarcat, no veia el problema en el codigo, estaba bloqueado!!!

Comment: también me funciono colocando simplemente for i in range(len(a))